# Avoid retrieve 'echo' print using ADO recordset in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, ado, recordset

I'm not a great expert of VBA and excel Macro but I need to exec an SQL macro that is present on the database.
This macro in its SQL definition performs some 'echo' operations (4 'echo' at the beginning
and 2 'echo' at the end) then the SQL macro retrieves 18 columns.
Removing the 'echo' the retrieval perform good, but I need to maintain the 'echo' in the SQL code because this macro is created automatically by the system.
To retrieve data from my external source I used ADO recordset as follows:

```
'If the recordset is empty
If (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    iReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="No data retrieved", _
        Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Error")
Else 'If the recordset contains data
    rs.MoveFirst
    Row = 2
    Do While (rs.EOF = False And rs.BOF = False)         
        p = rs.GetRows
        Sheet2.Range("A" & Row).Value = p(0, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("B" & Row).Value = p(1, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("C" & Row).Value = p(2, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("D" & Row).Value = p(3, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("E" & Row).Value = p(4, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("F" & Row).Value = p(5, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("G" & Row).Value = p(6, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("H" & Row).Value = p(7, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("I" & Row).Value = p(8, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("J" & Row).Value = p(9, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("K" & Row).Value = p(10, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("L" & Row).Value = p(11, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("M" & Row).Value = p(12, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("N" & Row).Value = p(13, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("O" & Row).Value = p(14, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("P" & Row).Value = p(15, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("Q" & Row).Value = p(16, 0)
        Sheet2.Range("R" & Row).Value = p(17, 0)
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop
End If
```

The fact is that with the 'echo' in the SQL macro only the first one 'echo' is retrieved and printed in my excel sheet in the first column, then it doesn't retrieve anything else, neither the others 'echo' nor the 18-columns data of my interesting.
I tried the recordset MoveNext and Move methods to move to the 5th position (because I thougth that the 5th position corresponds to the first 18-columns data, since I have 4 'echo' at the beginning) but it didn't work :(
Even moving to the second position doesn't work, so I conclude that in my recordset I have only one entry corresponding to the first 'echo', then the recordset reach its EOF and exit the loop.
Is there a way or a change in my code that avoid the retrieval of the 'echo' produced by the SQL macro?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a mistake in here, but I think you want something like this.  You only want to call GetRows once, because after you call it, it's the same as saying MoveLast.  The idea here is to dump the recordset into an array and then loop through every element of the "rows" (which is the 2nd dimension).  Within that, loop through columns 4 to 21, which I think skips over your "echos."

```
Dim p as Variant
Dim i as Long
Dim j as Long

'If the recordset is empty
If (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    iReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="No data retrieved", _
        Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Error")
Else 'If the recordset contains data
   'just fetch it once
   p = rs.GetRows
   'loop through the rows
   For i = Lbound(p,2) to Ubound(p,2)
      'loop through the columns that don't have "echo"
      For j = 4 to 21
        Sheet2.Cells(i,j-2).Value = p(j, i)
      Next j
   Next i
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Doug for your help, but it didn't work...the fact is that even with your piece of code the rs contains only the first 'echo' print and then nothing else...I tried to adjust it but (for now) without success... :D